# in python, does a data structure stay in scope when calling a function recursively

Tags: python, function, recursion, scope

,hello I have a depth first search function.  I want to use a list, but does the list hold through out a recursive call?

```
def depthFirstSearch(problem):
   visited = []
   movement =[]

   # test goal state
   #else search successor nodes and call depthFirstSearch on these
```

can I access visited in the recursive calls so I can see which nodes have been visited, or do I need to pass the list as a parameter?

also, movement moves the bot to the next node, you simply add the command inside and return it to the agent.  Do i need to return a list all the way through the recursive stacks, or can I simply add onto it in each recursive call?

Comment: Data structure doesn't stay in scope. It is refreshed for each recursive call. You have to pass it as parameters.

Comment: If your function is recursive, you don't need to keep track of which nodes have been visited.

Comment: actually you do.  I completed it, but one of the problems was cycles, or loops.  if you dont check for visited, you can go through a loop intinifly

Comment: @ForgottenOne Then you did it wrong. Can you show the code?

Answer (score 0):

It may be not the best solution, but it's a solution:

```
def depthFirstSearch(problem, visited=[], movement=[]):
    # Your code here...
```

The parameters are initialised at the function's declaration, and will persist until the end of execution. The recursive calls can access the lists even if its parent altered the local values of this parameters (and if you not override the parameters in the call, obviously).

If you are calling this function only once (not counting the recursive calls) you can do this way, else you may define this lists outside the function definition and also define a wrapper function, for example:

```
visited = []
movement = []

def depthFirstSearch(problem):
    visited.clear()
    movement.clear()
    recursiveSearch(problem)

def recursiveSearch(problem):
    visited.append(something)
    recursiveSearch(something_else)
    # More code...
    movement.etc()
```

Comment: The problem with defining mutable data structures as defaults is well known. I'd recommend the first solution, but modifying  it to check against None to set an empty list.